# Specific CSS Selector - Surround Element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following markup:

```
<a><div class="action_button">Log In</div></a>
```

I have styling on `.action_button` to make it bigger and have a background etc.

I also have styling on `.action_button:hover` to make it have a lighter background and an inset shadow when the user hovers on it.

How do I apply styling to the anchor tag that surrounds it, but only when it surrounds a `.action_button` div.

For example, this works:

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

But it affects all links, I only want to affect those that surround the `.action_button` divs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: never put block element inside an inline element it's a bad merkup

Comment: That said, I suggest you move the `action_button` class to the `a` and style it so it behaves like a block element. You don't need to explicitly create a `div` just so it functions like a block element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just:

```
<a class="action_button"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.action_button {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block; 
    /* other styles */
}
```

I don't see the point of having a DIV inside an A. If you want the anchor to be a block, just set `display: block` on that anchor directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
a .action_button:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: This styles the `div` not the `a`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code around slightly - the `<a>` should be nested inside the `<div>`, as the div is a block element and the anchor tag is inline.

Then you can simply use the following:

```
<style>
    .action_button a       {text-decoration:underline; }
    .action_button a:hover {text-decoration:none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a class to the "a" element that contains the button. you can't build a selector that works in the other direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery to add a class to every "a" that has a div with the class .action_button

```
$("a").has("div.action_button").addClass("myclass");
```

And then, obviously, use that class to select your "a" tags.

http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: jQuery is awesome.  Javascript solutions to CSS problems, not so much.